# Why this implementation of a pure function isn't considered to have external dependencies?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, pure-function

I'm fine with the `pure function` concept on pretty simple examples like...

```
function addTwo(val){
   return val + 2;
}
```

Given the same arguments, it yields the same result, leading to *Referential Transparency* and good deterministic code.

But then I've came across examples like these (taken from [professor frisby mostly adequate guide](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch3.html#the-case-for-purity), but I've found similar examples on other FP JS books)

```
//pure
var signUp = function(Db, Email, attrs) {
  return function() {
    var user = saveUser(Db, attrs);
    welcomeUser(Email, user);
  };
};

var saveUser = function(Db, attrs) {
  ...
};

var welcomeUser = function(Email, user) {
  ...
};
```

and I don't get why isn't considered an external dependency (so, impure) the call to `saveUser` or `welcomeUser`.

I know that from a function/IO point of view, `signUp` always return the "same" (an equivalent) wired function, but it feels weird to me.

It's difficult to me to understand why even

```
function multiplyBy(times){
  return value => value * times;
}
const fiveTimes = multiplyBy(5);
fiveTimes(10);
```

is considered `pure`. From the returned function POV, accesing to `times` is a lookup on the scope-chain, it could come from the immediate outer scope, or from beyond (like global scope).

Any one wants to bring some light to this?

Comment: How could `times` come from beyond the immediate outer scope?

Comment: Suppose it were `const multiply = ...` (ES2015). Would you still have a question about whether `fiveTimes` was pure? JavaScript isn't primarily a functional language (although it can mostly be used that way), so if the mutability of those identifiers is what's bothering you, the answer might be "by convention until we can use ES2015 we're assuming you leave function identifiers unchanged."

Comment: @squint in my snippet is no other way, but what i'm trying to say (I'm not a native english speaker) is that, if you take the returned function in isolation and examine the body (value * times) times isn't present on the signature, so it grabs from the scope via lookup on the scope-chain. Therefore it seems pretty impure.

Comment: I see what you're getting at. By design it's pure, but there's no language/implementation level enforcement. It's not in isolation, however if you didn't see the full code, you'd not know that and would need to "trust" a claim of purity. Doesn't make it less of a pure function; it's just that your guarantees come from elsewhere.

Comment: In functional speak, the signature of `multiplyBy` would be something like `multiplyBy:: a -> b -> c`; `multiplyBy` takes an argument `a` and returns a function which takes an argument `b` and returns a value `c`. The second one, *function which takes a `b`*, is a type in itself. `multiplyBy` creates a new type, a function `b => b * 5`. That's pretty darn pure.

Comment: You are way too dogmatic for Javascript. It is a multi paradigm language that means, it cannot please anyone - actually Javascript is really good at disappointing everyone (FP, OOP or whatever).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My explanation for function purity in JavaScript is that there's no such thing as a binary "pure" or "impure", but rather a spectrum of confidence that a function will behave predictably. There's all kinds of tricks that can be played to make a function that seems pure not be, by passing an object with a side-effect getter on it, for example.

So, once we realize that purity is about degree of confidence, we can then ask, how confident am I that some function will behave the way I expect? If that function references another function, how sure are you that the other function is pure? And, moreover, how sure are you that the identifier that's referencing that other function doesn't / can't get re-assigned to point to some other function you aren't aware of?

I personally code my programs so that I almost never re-define an identifier that's pointing at a function, especially if that function is declared rather than just a function expression. In that way, I feel very confident (say, 99.99%) that if `foo(..)` calls `bar(..)`, and I'm confident that `bar(..)` is reliably pure, then `foo(..)` is also reliably pure, because I know I won't reassign `bar(..)` to any other function and cause surprising results.

Some people even go so far as to define their function identifiers with `const fn = function ..`. I don't think that helps all that much... it probably would take my confidence level from 99.99% to 99.999%. That doesn't move the needle enough to justify its usage, IMO.

Moreover, on the closure part of your question: if an inner function closes over an outer variable that's still contained in a pure function, and nothing re-assigns that variable, then it's *effectively* a constant, so my level of confidence is very high in the predictability.

But again, the take away is that function purity in JS is about level of confidence, not an absolute binary yes or no.

Comment: _level of confidence_ sounds appropriate for two developers working on the same project but not for a programming language, which is an essential part of the web. Frightening!

Comment: I think of *level of confidence* as a loose contract between writer and reader of a piece of code. The writer can do more or less to increase the effectiveness of that contract, resulting in more or less readability for the reader.

Answer (score 6):

The definition of a *pure function* is:

> A function that does always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s) and that does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices.

"Having dependencies" plays absolutely no role in defining a pure function. The only thing that matters is whether the function has any **side effects** and whether its result depends on **external state**. If a function behaves exactly the same and always produces the same result given the same input, it is pure. If a function has any side effects (modifies global state) or behaves differently depending on external state, it is impure. A function may have a dependency on (read: *call*) another function as part of its operation; as long as that other function is also pure, that doesn't taint the purity.

The `signUp` example you show is pure, because it only acts on its input and always returns the exact same output when called with the same input. Note that the function itself doesn't "do" anything. It's not calling the database or produce any side effect. All it does is return a function. But this returned function is always the same if the input is the same. That returned function is in effect impure; but the function that produced it is not.

Comment: *"The signUp example you show is pure, because it only acts on its input and always returns the exact same output when called with the same input."* ...unless you change what `saveUser` and `welcomeUser` refer to, which I think is the point of the question.

Comment: Yep, I've expected that saveUser and welcomeUser were params as well, maybe they show examples like that to "keep it simple" and to begin to grasp the concept.

Comment: This is merely *function composition*. `signUp` refers to two other *pure* functions, which does not taint its purity. Yes, it's a *dependency*, but has nothing to do with purity. Consider `(a, b) => a + b`: what if in your language of choice `+` was actually a function (*cough* Haskell *cough*), `(a, b) => add(a, b)`? Then `+` is an external dependency. Does that make the function impure? No. Must all dependencies be injected as parameters to preserve purity? No. – Indeed, if you change the `saveUser` dependency to an impure function, well… then everything breaks down indeed.

Comment: Something to note is that the function returned by `signUp` is more a procedure than a function _per se_ due the lack of return. i.e. I'm trying to figure out how to test this `signUp`, but this is matter to other question I guess.

Comment: @sminutoli That's mostly a matter of nomenclature. A function without a return value will presumably have a side effect instead, otherwise it'd be pretty useless. So calling it an *"impure function"* is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: depending of external state === side effect

Comment: @Sylwester External *state*: yes; mere external function/symbol definition: that's not a side effect in itself.

Comment: @deceze free variables that don't change from their creation is not a problem for pureness so I guessed your external state was subject to mutation either by the function itself or perhaps something else that changed it. To depend on such binding would itself be a side effect.