# is a function pure if it uses const declared pure function in the scope?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```js
const pureFunc = (x) => x + 1

const isPureFunc = (x) => {
  return pureFunc(x) + 1
}
```

Even though a function uses a const declared pure function without dependency, is the function a pure function?

Comment: This particular function is pure because it meets the two criteria: (1) the output is the same for the same input (i.e., it's deterministic), and (2) there are no side effects

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834458/why-this-implementation-of-a-pure-function-isnt-considered-to-have-external-dep/39834974

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the result is depend on its own args, not from the other.
The result of this is not changed from the other function but changed if the x  argument will change.

So it is pure function.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that this function **isn't pure**,
its return value depends on a global function that cannot be controlled... The referential transparency principle states that, given the same input, a function must yield the same output. However, the dependency on `pureFunc` constitutes a violation (it could change, or be non-pure itself).

to be pure, or "by-the-book-pure", it should be refactored this way:

```js
const isPureFunc = (fn, x) => {
  return fn(x) + 1
}

const pureFunc = (x) => x + 1;

const result = isPureFunc(pureFunc, 5);
```

---

With this said, of course, we don't need to be "that" academic, and accept this overall program as pure program since the `pureFunc` function is "actually" under control.